# SonarQube integration in Android Project error's

Tags: android, gitlab, sonarqube, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to integrate SonarQube in Android Project with GitLab Ci.

This is my **build.gradle**  file

```
apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"
sonarqube {
    androidVariant 'release'
    properties {
        property "sonar.projectKey", "*********"
        property "sonar.qualitygate.wait", true
        property "sonar.host.url", "https://******/sonarqube"
        property "sonar.login", "******"
        property "sonar.projectName", "test digital"
        property "sonar.tests", ["src/test/java"]
        property "sonar.test.inclusions", "**/*Test*/**"
        property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"
        property "sonar.sources", "src/main/java"
        property "sonar.exclusions", '**/*Test*/**,' +
                '*.json,' +
                '**/*test*/**,' +
                '**/.gradle/**,' +
                '**/R.class'
    }
}
```

this is my **.gitlab-ci.yml** file

```
stages:
  - sonarqube-check

sonarqube-check:
  tags:
    - gr1004
  image: adoptopenjdk:17-jre
  variables:
    SONAR_USER_HOME: "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.sonar"  # Defines the location of the analysis task cache
    GIT_DEPTH: "0"  # Tells git to fetch all the branches of the project, required by the analysis task
  cache:
    key: "${CI_JOB_NAME}"
    paths:
      - .sonar/cache
  script:
      - ./gradlew sonarqube
  stage: sonarqube-check
  allow_failure: true
  only:
    - merge_requests
    - master
```

my project using **JDK17**

Before running the job, I tried to execute it manually, and afterward, I encountered a recurring error as follows

[error_message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYuZ4.png)

Who can assist me? Or who can provide a guide on how to integrate SonarQube into an Android project using GitLab CI?"